# When did Google index a page?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, information-extraction

How can I find out (any language but better if Python) when Google indexed a specific html page?

Ideally I would have a list of URLs to check for.

I have already tried the WayBack machine but it doesn't have the majority of the pages I need. Also if anyone can suggest an API to extract dates in multiple language from text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern to access the cached version of your webpage.

```
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:<URL>
```

Say for example, you can see the cache version of my blog datafireball.com like this, as you can see, it is indexed `20141020, 23:33:30`, `strip=` will avoid loading javascript, css..etc. To get the time when the indexed was index, you can use some browser automation tool like Selenium or Phantomjs... etc. to get the page.

[image]